# Google map javascript api url difference

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-api

What's the difference between google api url 
[https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js)?key={api_key}
which is not working now and return error when using on a map to populate coordinates, and  [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=)?key={api_key} which is working fine.

Comment: One uses the SSL protocol (starts with https://) whereas the other is a plain HTTP request (starts with http://).  SSL is considered more secure for requests as data is encrypted by the browser before it is sent.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470523/how-does-ssl-really-work) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

According to the google maps documentation, the "googleapis" (V3) is the standard now. Maybe for mayor security because it use "https" secure connection instead of regular "http" or even core changes in the API.

Here is the steps for update your site:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3