# Python - urllib.open - "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error

Tags: python

I want to download a file from a website but when i use urlopen i have an error :

url= 'https://dpdhl.com/content/dam/dpdhl/en/media-center/investors/documents/statbooks/2021/DPDHL-Statbook-Q4-FY-2020.xlsx'

urll = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'dpdhl.com'. (_ssl.c:1123)>

Someone can help me.
Best regards

Comment: The website needs to update their certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error in your code. HTTPS uses [SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470523/how-does-ssl-really-work) (Secure Socket Layer) and the target website provided an invalid certificate. Change https to http and it will work, but you lose the security of SSL.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answer. 
I changed https to http, i don't have error but i don't have response, the script is always running.